# Hide File Extensions Only On Desktop

Tags: windows, windows-registry, file-extension

Is it possible to hide file extensions only on a specific folder? (Desktop in my case)
I want all the extensions to be shown on my PC but I have a few programs that are only an exe file without an extension on my desktop like putty for exemple that I'd like to be named only "putty" and not "putty.exe".

Comment: As others said. But you can implement a context menu item to quickly show or hide file extensions (toggle the setting).

Comment: Just add shortcuts to the programs instead of copies of the programs to your desktop. You can name the shortcuts however you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Showing file extensions is a global setting, it can't be separated from folder to folder. (or folder to desktop)